# map literals neo4j 2.01

Tags: properties, neo4j

I'm using `neo4j 2.01`
Could you please tell me how to make this map literals work?

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MERGE (n:person {name:'Alice', age:38, address:{city:'London', residential:true}}) RETURN n;

MatchError: Map(city -> London, residential -> true) (of class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2)
```

Thank you in advance for your kind help.
Marco

Answer (score 1):

Map literals are only allowed in the `RETURN` clause. Neo4j properties on nodes are either primitives, Strings or arrays of them. If you want to store a more complex value with a node, decompose the complex value into a set of nodes and relationships and attach it to your entity node with a relationship:

```
MERGE (n:person {name:'Alice', age:38})-[:LIVES_IN]->(a:address {city:'London', residential:true}}) RETURN n,a;
```

Even the `residential` flag is implicitly encoded into the relationship as `LIVES_IN`, so you might omit it and rely on verbose relationship types.

To use map literals in `RETURN`:

```
match (n:person)-[:LIVES_IN]->(a:address) return {name:n.name, age:n.age, address:a}
```